# Cisco C220 M3, How to install Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, raid, cisco

I have to install Ubuntu 16.04 to Cisco C220 M3s server.

Install without RAID is okay.
But use RAID1, Cannot install ubuntu 16.04.
Most time error is from Grub or make Partion.
(RAID1 is must need)

I find C220 m3 in Ubuntu Hardwear matching page.
But I can't install.

Please, Is here any way to install?

Comment: Does the computer boot from legacy BIOS or UEFI/GPT? Depending on that possible duplicates are [How to Install Ubuntu 14.04 with RAID 1 using desktop installer?](/q/505446/175814) or [How to install Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit with a dual-boot RAID 1 partition on an UEFI/GPT system?](/q/660023/175814). (2 minutes of [searching](/search?q=install+ubuntu+raid+1), you’re welcome)

Comment: Is it an Ubuntu server or desktop image?

Answer (score 0):

Links on the Internet does not help much. The Cisco UCS C220 M3 only supports RHEL (Fedora/Redhat/CentOS) and releases their binary firmwares for these distros. For Debian/Ubuntu you need non-free firmwares loaded on your installation media (if Debian) or the right distro for Ubuntu (14.04 LTS I believe)